# Regex to replace Markdown characters not inside backticks

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that `replaces` any markdown specific character (to be escaped, `` [\*_{}[\]()#+\-.!`] ``) not inside **single or triple backticks**.  This is being implemented in Javascript.  A couple examples:

1. `` foo `bar` baz.qux `quux` ``  -> should replace `.` in `baz.qux` with `\\.&`
2. `` foo `bar.baz` foo_bar `` -> should replace `_` with `\\_&` in `foo_bar`, but not `.` in `bar.baz`

This is what I have right now: `` markdown.replace(/[\\*_{}[\]()#+\-.!`]/g, '\\$&') ``, but it matches `.` in `` `foo.bar` ``.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: See ```(`(?:``)?).*?\1(*SKIP)(*F)|[*_{}[\]()#+\-.!`]``` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jryZTM/1/). The rest depends where and how you are using the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the quick reply.  I forgot to mention this is being used in Javascript.  Your solution works well, but I'm not sure how to implement in JS.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No one can have any idea right now as you did not provide details: what are you doing? Replacing/removing/extracting... Show your code.

Comment: Sorry -- I'm trying to `replace` any markdown specific character not inside `backticks`. This is what I have right now:

`markdown.replace(/[\\*_{}[\]()#+\-.!]/g, '\\$&')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
markdown.replace(/(`(?:``)?).*?\1|[\\*_{}[\]()#+\-.!`]/g, 
    (x, y) => y ? y : `\\${x}`)
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const markdown = 'foo `bar` baz.qux `quux` and foo `bar.baz` foo_bar';
console.log(
    markdown.replace(/(`(?:``)?).*?\1|[\\*_{}[\]()#+\-.!`]/g, 
        (x, y) => y ? x : `\\${x}`)
)
```

*Details*:

- ``` (`(?:``)?).*?\1 ``` - a single or triple backticks (captured into Group 1, `\1`), then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then the same amount of backticks as captured into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `` [\\*_{}[\]()#+\-.!`] `` - a char from the set, `\`, `*`, `_`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `#`, `+`, `-`, `.`, `!` or backtick.

The replacement is a callable, where Group 1 is defined as `y`, and `x` is the whole match value. If Group 1 matched (see `y ?`),  the replacement is the whole match (the substrings between backticks), else, the return value is a backslash + the matched char.